# Recover Redmine data from production log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, redmine

I had a project in Redmine with more than 600 issues. I moved all the issues to a different project. I had no idea that the move deletes all the data for the custom fields!

So all the custom field values are now lost. I did not backup the database before this action as I really did not think that I was going to do any harm by moving issues as moving is a native function in the UI.

What I noticed is though that the production.log contains events for all creation and updates. All my 600 issues are in order in the production log. How can I use these log statements to repeat the actions? If I can import all the log actions, I can migrate the custom fields that it writes to the original Redmine instance and restore my values.

Entries look like this:

```
Processing IssuesController#update (for XX.XX.XX.X at 2013-02-07 11:19:54) [PUT]
Parameters: {"_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"nWNSSRYjHhN0BGb+Ya8M4pYWPPgsfdM=", "issue"=>{"assigned_to_id"=>"", "custom_field_values"=>{"10"=>"", "5"=>"Not translated", "1"=>"fi", "8"=>"http://screencast.com/t/ODknR8K", "9"=>"", "3"=>"", "4"=>""}, "done_ratio"=>"0", "due_date"=>"", "priority_id"=>"4", "estimated_hours"=>"", "start_date"=>"2013-02-07", "subject"=>"1\tInstallation in English", "tracker_id"=>"1", "lock_version"=>"0", "description"=>"Steps:\r\nOpen Nitro\r\n\r\nProblem:\r\nNot localized"}, "controller"=>"issues", "time_entry"=>{"hours"=>"", "activity_id"=>"", "comments"=>""}, "attachments"=>{"1"=>{"description"=>""}}, "id"=>"3876", "action"=>"update", "commit"=>"Submit", "notes"=>""}
```

I am really hoping that there is a way, any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you talked to their support folks to get their ideas? That would be the first thing to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a decent text editor and/or spreadsheet application and do a massive find and replace and construct a series of UPDATE SQL commands and run them directly on the database (TEST FIRST!!)

- Extract from log
- Remove unnessary information
- Copy into spreadsheet
- Split text into columns
- Add in columns with necessary SQL commands "UPDATE  SET etc" copy into all rows of this column etc.
- Join columns to make one text command per row
- Export joined data to a text file
- Run against test database as sql
- If all goes well run against production database as sql

Comment: Wasn't the easiest task to do but I have done something similar. Wrote a pearl script and converted it to a csv first where I had to manually clean/up map items. Then used another pearl script and converted that data to insert statements...

Answer (score 0):

The log entry, following "Parameters:", looks like a regular Ruby hash definition. I'd parse that out and `eval` it back into a hash variable.

From there you will need to peel off elements and insert them into a database. I'd do that using Sequel, but use what works for you.

Talk to the RedMine support people and get the schema for their tables so you can figure out what data goes where and the database driver needed.